# Hyperledger Fabric: How can I make an organization both peer and orderer nodes?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am building a Hyperledger Fabric network, and I am trying to make an organization have both a peer node and an ordering node. I am using cryptogen to generate the certs and keys, and am only creating one organization as a "peer organization". I had one network that had 6 organizations--5 of which had a single peer and one orderer organization with a single orderer. Then I took these configuration files and removed the orderer organization and added an orderer endpoint to one of the peer organizations. I am now getting an error.

printed to the screen:

> Error: failed to create deliver client for orderer: orderer client failed to connect to localhost:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded

Error message from running "docker logs orderer.orgname.domain"

> 2020-08-17 23:56:43.834 UTC [orderer.common.server] Main -> INFO 00d Beginning to serve requests

> 2020-08-17 23:56:51.317 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 00e TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.21.0.1:32892

my configtx.yaml file

```
Organizations:
- &orgname
    Name: orgnameMSP
    SkipAsForeign: false
    ID: orgnameMSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname.domain/msp
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('orgnameMSP.admin', 'orgnameMSP.peer', 'PSUMSP.client')"
        Writers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('orgnameMSP.admin', 'orgnameMSP.client')"
        Admins:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('orgnameMSP.admin')"
        Endorsement:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('orgnameMSP.member')"

    OrdererEndpoints:
            - orderer.orgname.domain:7050
    AnchorPeers:
        - Host: peer0.orgname.domain
          Port: 7051

- &orgname2
    Name: orgname2MSP
    ID: orgname2MSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname2.domain/msp
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('orgname2MSP.admin', 'orgname2MSP.peer', 'orgname2MSP.client')"
        Writers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('orgname2MSP.admin', 'orgname2MSP.client')"
        Admins:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('orgname2MSP.admin')"
        Endorsement:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('orgname2MSP.peer')"

    AnchorPeers:
        - Host: peer0.orgname2.domain
          Port: 8051

- &orgname3
    Name: orgname3MSP
    ID: orgname3MSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname3.domain/msp
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('orgname3MSP.admin', 'orgname3MSP.peer', 'orgname3MSP.client')"
        Writers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('orgname3MSP.admin', 'orgname3MSP.client')"
        Admins:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('orgname3MSP.admin')"
        Endorsement:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('orgname3MSP.peer')"
    AnchorPeers:
        - Host: peer0.orgname3.domain
          Port: 9051

- &orgname4
    Name: orgname4
    ID: orgname4MSP

    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname4.domain/msp
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('orgname4MSP.admin', 'orgname4MSP.peer', 'orgname4MSP.client')"
        Writers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('orgname4MSP.admin', 'orgname4MSP.client')"
        Admins:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('orgname4MSP.admin')"
        Endorsement:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('orgname4MSP.peer')"
    AnchorPeers:
        - Host: peer0.orgname4.domain
          Port: 10051

- &orgname5
    Name: Fly-Us-HospitalityMSP
    ID: Fly-Us-HospitalityMSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname5.domain/msp

    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('orgname5MSP.admin', 'orgname5MSP.peer', 'orgname5MSP.client')"
        Writers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('orgname5MSP.admin', 'orgname5MSP.client')"
        Admins:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('orgname5MSP.admin')"
        Endorsement:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('orgname5MSP.peer')"
    AnchorPeers:
        - Host: peer0.orgname5.domain
          Port: 11051

Capabilities:
Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
    #        V2_0: true
    V1_4_2: true

Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
    #        V2_0: true
    V1_4_2: true

Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
    #        V2_0: true
    V1_4_2: true

Application: &ApplicationDefaults

Organizations:

Policies:
    Readers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    LifecycleEndorsement:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
    Endorsement:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"

Capabilities:
    <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

OrdererType: solo

EtcdRaft:
    Consenters:
    - Host: orderer.orgname.domain
      Port: 7050
      ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname.domain/peers/peer0.orgname.domain/tls/server.crt
      ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname.domain/peers/peer0.orgname.domain/tls/server.crt

Addresses:
    - orderer.orgname.domain:7050
BatchTimeout: 2s
BatchSize:
    MaxMessageCount: 10
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
Organizations:
Policies:
    Readers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    BlockValidation:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Writers"

Channel: &ChannelDefaults
Policies:
    Readers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
Capabilities:
    <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Profiles:
BasicChannel:
    Consortium: MyConsortium
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *orgname
            - *orgname2
            - *orgname3
            - *orgname4
            - *orgname5
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

OrdererGenesis:
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Orderer:
        <<: *OrdererDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *orgname
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
    Consortiums:
        MyConsortium:
            Organizations:
            - *orgname
            - *orgname2
            - *orgname3
            - *orgname4
            - *orgname5
```

My docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: "2"
networks:
  network2.3:

services:
  ca-orgname:
    container_name: ca.orgname.domain
    hostname: ca.orgname.domain
    extends:
      file: docker-ca-base.yaml
      service: ca-base
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.orgname.domain
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.orgname.domain-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls/tlscs.orgname.domain-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname.domain/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname.domain/tslca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls

  ca-orgname2:
    container_name: ca.orgname2.domain
    hostname: ca.orgname2.domain
    extends:
      file: docker-ca-base.yaml
      service: ca-base
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.orgname2.domain
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.orgname2.domain-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls/tlscs.orgname2.domain-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=8054
    ports:
      - "8054:7054"
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname2.domain/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname2.domain/tslca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls

  ca-orgname3:
    container_name: ca.orgname3.domain
    hostname: ca.orgname3.domain
    extends:
      file: docker-ca-base.yaml
      service: ca-base
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.orgname3.domain
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.orgname3.domain-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls/tlscs.orgname3.domain-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=9054
    ports:
      - "9054:7054"
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname3.domain/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname3.domain/tslca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls

  ca-orgname4:
    container_name: ca.orgname4.domain
    hostname: ca.orgname4.domain
    extends:
      file: docker-ca-base.yaml
      service: ca-base
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.orgname4.domain
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.orgname4.domain-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls/tlscs.orgname4.domain-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=10054
    ports:
      - "10054:7054"
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname4.domain/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname4.domain/tslca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls

  ca-orgname5:
    container_name: ca.orgname5.domain
    hostname: ca.orgname5.domain
    extends:
      file: docker-ca-base.yaml
      service: ca-base
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.orgname5.domain
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.orgname5.domain-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls/tlscs.orgname5.domain-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=11054
    ports:
      - "11054:7054"
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname5.domain/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname5.domain/tslca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls

  orderer.orgname.domain
    container_name: orderer.orgname.domain
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest
    dns_search: .
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=PSUMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderers
    command: orderer
    volumes:
      - ../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/genesis.block
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname.domain/peers/peer0.orgname.domain/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname.domain/peers/peer0.orgname.domain/tls:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
    ports:
      - 7050:7050

  peer0.orgname.domain:
    container_name: peer0.orgname.domain
    extends:
      file: docker-peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=orgnameMSP
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.orgname.domain
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.orgname.domain:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.orgname.domain:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.orgname.domain:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.orgname.domain:7051
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname.domain/peers/peer0.orgname.domain/msp:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname.domain/peers/peer0.orgname.domain/tls:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls
      - /var/run:/host/var/run
      - ../channel-artifacts:/etc/hyperledger/channel
    ports:
      - 7051:7051

  peer0.orgname2.domain:
    container_name: peer0.orgname2.domain
    extends:
      file: docker-peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=orgname2MSP
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.orgname2.domain
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.orgname2.domain:8051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.orgname2.domain:8052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.orgname2.domain:8051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.orgname2.domain:8051
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname2.domain/peers/peer0.orgname2.domain/msp:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname2.domain/peers/peer0.orgname2.domain/tls:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls
      - /var/run:/host/var/run
      - ../channel-artifacts:/etc/hyperledger/channel
    ports:
      - 8051:8051

  peer0.orgname3.domain:
    container_name: peer0.orgname3.domain
    extends:
      file: docker-peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=orgname3MSP
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.orgname3.domain
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.orgname3.domain:9051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.orgname3.domain:9052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.orgname3.domain:9051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.orgname3.domain:9051
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname3.domain/peers/peer0.orgname3.domain/msp:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname3.domain/peers/peer0.orgname3.domain/tls:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls
      - /var/run:/host/var/run
      - ../channel-artifacts:/etc/hyperledger/channel
    ports:
      - 9051:9051

  peer0.orgname4.domain:
    container_name: peer0.orgname4.domain
    extends:
      file: docker-peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=orgname4MSP
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.orgname4.domain
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.orgname4.domain:10051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:10051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.orgname4.domain:10052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:10052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.orgname4.domain:10051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.orgname4.domain:10051
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname4.domain/peers/peer0.orgname4.domain/msp:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname4.domain/peers/peer0.orgname4.domain/tls:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls
      - /var/run:/host/var/run
      - ../channel-artifacts:/etc/hyperledger/channel
    ports:
      - 10051:10051

  peer0.orgname5.domain:
    container_name: peer0.orgname5.domain
    extends:
      file: docker-peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=orgname5MSP
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.orgname5.domain
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.orgname5.domain:11051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:11051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.orgname5.domain:11052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:11052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.orgname5.domain:11051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.orgname5.domain:11051
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname5.domain/peers/peer0.orgname5.domain/msp:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgname5.domain/peers/peer0.orgname5.domain/tls:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls
      - /var/run:/host/var/run
      - ../channel-artifacts:/etc/hyperledger/channel
    ports:
      - 11051:11051
```

My crypto-config.yaml file

```
    PeerOrgs:
      - Name: orgname
        Domain: orgname.domain
        EnableNodeOUs: true

        Template:
          Count: 1
          SANS:
            - "localhost"
          Users:
            Count: 1

      - Name: orgname2
        Domain: orgname2.domain
        EnableNodeOUs: true

        Template:
          Count: 1
          SANS:
            - "localhost"
        Users:
          Count: 1

      - Name: orgname3
        Domain: orgname3.domain
        EnableNodeOUs: true

        Template:
          Count: 1
          SANS:
            - "localhost"
        Users:
          Count: 1

      - Name: orgname4
        Domain: orgname4.domain
        EnableNodeOUs: true

        Template:
          Count: 1
          SANS:
            - "localhost"
        Users:
          Count: 1

      - Name: orgname5
        Domain: orgname5.domain
        EnableNodeOUs: true

        Template:
          Count: 1
          SANS:
            - "localhost"
        Users:
          Count: 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
So I changed my configuration of cryptoconfig.yaml to create two peers in the peer/orderer organization. One I designated as the orderer, the other as a peer. This got rid of the TLS error, but now I have an error with my endorsement policy.

> 020-08-20 14:29:09.699 PDT [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
> Error: got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied

The rest of the files are the same, except I changed the orderer TLS files to point to the new designated "orderer" (actually a peer as far cryptogen is concerned) files.

Comment: The error is "bad certificate" , are you using a docker-compose file ? Can you update your post to upload it ? For me , it's that you didn't mounted the right certificate on the corresponding peer

Comment: @jnaworld223 Can you share your `crypto-config.yaml` file?

Comment: @Popopame yes I am using a docker-compose file. I don't think I missed any volumes, but I could be wrong. I have edited the post to include it.

Comment: @alpha I have edited the post to include it.

Comment: @jnasworld223 Can you add `127.0.0.1` too under `SANS` and re-create the crypto-config directory? I generally use names like `orderer1.example.com` and `peer1.myorg.com` under `SANS` and then add a mapping like `127.0.0.1 orderer1.example.com` in `/etc/hosts`. Recently I faced an issue related too tls cert even though the `localhost` was already present under `SANS` but adding `127.0.0.1` under `SANS` fixed it for me.

Comment: @alpha Thanks for the advise, but unfortunately that did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with TLS was solved by creating two peers under the organization orgname, and designating one for the orderer. I don't understand exactly why I couldn't use the same certificates for both the peer and orderer node, but it is working now.

The second issue I had in my update was solved by making the endorsement policies more permissive. For each organization in my configtx.yaml file, I set Readers, Writers, and Endorsements to require any member signature.